# Get component state from child component inside Parent and do conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component like this,

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.js";
import { FaCoffee, FaCrosshairs } from "react-icons/fa";

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Topic 1" },
        { id: 2, name: "Topic 2" },
        { id: 3, name: "Topic 3" }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    let data = this.state.data;
    let lists = data.map((d) => {
      return (
        <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <p key={d.id}>{d.name}</p>
          <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
            <ChildComponent id={d.id}></ChildComponent>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
              Base on the component status do something. If in-progress then do
              nothing. If Complete then show <FaCrosshairs />
              If review-required then show <FaCoffee />
              etc inside this p tag.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{lists}</div>;
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Now inside this component, I am listing some topics. Now each topic has its own status. Now, to generate the status, I am using a child component.

Now for the sake of simplicity, I have some hard-coded status inside the child component and it's randomly displaying.

This is my child component,

```
import React from "react";

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      calculatedStatus: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setComponentState();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      this.setComponentState();
    }
  }
  setComponentState = () => {
    var textArray = ["in-progress", "review-required", "complete"];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
    var randomElement = textArray[randomIndex];
    this.setState({ calculatedStatus: randomElement });
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.calculatedStatus}</div>;
  }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Now If You run the application, something like this will be shown.
Now based on the status from ChildComponent, I want to show some icons as mentioned in the parent component.
Please help me. Thanks.

Here is a working fiddle ,
[Demo App](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-williamson-0m0d2h?file=/src/ChildComponent.js:0-722)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate from child to parent component in different ways. But in React it is preferred to communicate state only in the other direction. I would first recommend that you consider to lift up your state to the parent component and only forward the content you want to display.

E.g. like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent.js";
import { FaCoffee, FaCrosshairs } from "react-icons/fa";

const getComponentState = () => {
    var textArray = ["in-progress", "review-required", "complete"];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
    var randomElement = textArray[randomIndex];
    return randomElement;
};

class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "Topic 1", calculatedStatus : getComponentState() },
        { id: 2, name: "Topic 2", calculatedStatus: getComponentState() },
        { id: 3, name: "Topic 3", calculatedStatus : getComponentState() }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    let data = this.state.data;
    let lists = data.map((d) => {
      return (
        <div style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          <p key={d.id}>{d.name}</p>
          <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
            <ChildComponent id={d.id} status={d.calculatedStatus}></ChildComponent>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
              {d.calculatedStatus === 'review-required' && <FaCoffee />}
              {d.calculatedStatus === 'complete' && <FaCrosshairs />}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{lists}</div>;
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Otherwise, you would need to inform the parent with a provided handler function as property, e.g. `onStatusAssigned(id, status)`. But that's not so clean as solution as the above. And lastly, you could use React-Refs, which allow you direct access from parent to shared children state. See here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

Comment: Thanks , your approach is nice and clean :) thanks for the suggestion. I mark as accepted :) Cheers